# Can't delete email using MAPI

Tags: c#, email, outlook, com-interop, mapi

I've created Outlook 2019 add-in in C# and trying to use `DeleteMessages` method from MAPI to delete single email. However I'm always getting `E_INVALIDARG` as a result (look at code below).

I've checked following article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455823/Managed-MAPI-Part-1-Logon-MAPI-Session-and-Retriev, did some own changes and got the code below (only necessary code for `IMAPIFolder` and `HRESULT`, let's assume that I only support x64).

```
public interface IMAPIFolder
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    HRESULT DeleteMessages(IntPtr lpMsgList, uint ulUIParam, IntPtr lpProgress, uint ulFlags);
}
```

```
public enum HRESULT
{
    E_INVALIDARG = 0x80070057
}
```

```
public class EntryID
{
    private byte[] id_;
    
    public EntryID(byte[] id) 
    {
        id_ = id;
    }

    public static EntryID GetEntryID(string entryID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryID))
            return null;
        int count = entryID.Length / 2;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(entryID);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if ((2 * i + 2) > s.Length)
                return null;
            string s1 = s.ToString(2 * i, 2);
            if (!Byte.TryParse(s1, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null as IFormatProvider, out bytes[i]))
                return null;
        }
        return new EntryID(bytes);
    }
}
```

Code snippets to call `DeleteMessages` I've tried so far (item is MailItem object):

1.==================

```
string mailItemEntryId = ((MailItem)item).EntryID
byte[] msgEntryId = EntryID.GetEntryID(mailItemEntryId).AsByteArray;

int idLen = msgEntryId.Length;

IntPtr pMsgCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(16);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pMsgCom, 1L);
IntPtr pArrayCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(16);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pMsgCom, 8, (long)pArrayCom);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pArrayCom, (long)idLen);
IntPtr entryBytesCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(idLen);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pArrayCom, 8, (long)entryBytesCom);
Marshal.Copy(msgEntryId, 0, entryBytesCom, idLen);

var mapifolder = (IMAPIFolder)((MAPIFolder)mailItem.Parent).MAPIOBJECT
var result = mapifolder.DeleteMessages(pMsgCom, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

2.==================

```
string mailItemEntryId = ((MailItem)item).EntryID
byte[] msgEntryId = EntryID.GetEntryID(mailItemEntryId).AsByteArray;

int idLen = msgEntryId.Length;

IntPtr pMsgCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(12);
Marshal.WriteInt32(pMsgCom, 1);
IntPtr pArrayCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(12);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pMsgCom, 4, (long)pArrayCom);
Marshal.WriteInt32(pArrayCom, idLen);
IntPtr entryBytesCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(idLen);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pArrayCom, 4, (long)entryBytesCom);
Marshal.Copy(msgEntryId, 0, entryBytesCom, idLen);

var mapifolder = (IMAPIFolder)((MAPIFolder)mailItem.Parent).MAPIOBJECT
var result = mapifolder.DeleteMessages(pMsgCom, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

3.==================

```
string mailItemEntryId = ((MailItem)item).EntryID
byte[] msgEntryId = EntryID.GetEntryID(mailItemEntryId).AsByteArray;

int idLen = msgEntryId.Length;

IntPtr pMsgCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(16);
Marshal.WriteInt32(pMsgCom, 1);
IntPtr pArrayCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(16);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pMsgCom, 8, (long)pArrayCom);
Marshal.WriteInt32(pArrayCom, idLen);
IntPtr entryBytesCom = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(idLen);
Marshal.WriteInt64(pArrayCom, 8, (long)entryBytesCom);
Marshal.Copy(msgEntryId, 0, entryBytesCom, idLen);

var mapifolder = (IMAPIFolder)((MAPIFolder)mailItem.Parent).MAPIOBJECT
var result = mapifolder.DeleteMessages(pMsgCom, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

4.==================

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SBinary
{
    public uint cb;
    public IntPtr lpb;

    public static SBinary SBinaryCreate(byte[] data)
    {
        SBinary b;
        b.cb = (uint)data.Length;
        b.lpb = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)b.cb);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.cb; i++)
        {
            Marshal.WriteByte(b.lpb, i, data[i]);
        }
        return b;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SBinaryArray
{
    public uint cValues;
    public IntPtr lpbin;

    public static SBinaryArray SBinaryArrayCreate(uint length, IntPtr buffer)
    {
        SBinaryArray b;
        b.cValues = length;
        b.lpbin = buffer;
        return b;
    }
}

string mailItemEntryId = ((MailItem)item).EntryID
byte[] msgEntryId = EntryID.GetEntryID(mailItemEntryId).AsByteArray;

SBinary messageBin = SBinary.SBinaryCreate(msgEntryId);
IntPtr messageBinPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(messageBin));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(messageBin, messageBinPtr, false);

SBinaryArray messageBinArray = SBinaryArray.SBinaryArrayCreate(1, messageBinPtr);
IntPtr messageBinArrayPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(messageBinArray));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(messageBinArray, messageBinArrayPtr, false);

var mapifolder = (IMAPIFolder)((MAPIFolder)mailItem.Parent).MAPIOBJECT
var result = mapifolder.DeleteMessages(messageBinArrayPtr, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

I also tried to use `OpenEntry` (from `MAPISession`) and then `Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown` to get `IMAPIFolder` object. However the result was the same and got `E_INVALIDARG` for `DeleteMessages`. Any ideas why `DeleteMessages` returns `E_INVALIDARG`?

Answer (score 0):

`DeleteMesages` takes `SBinaryArray`. Its first element (`cValues`) is always 4 bytes, not 8 (you are using `WriteInt64`). Next is the pointer to the entry id (if you specify only one entry). Its size is 4 bytes under x86 and 8 bytes under x64. Use `IntPtr.Size`.

Comment: I changed the code and used 4 bytes for `cValues`. However result is still the same - `E_INVALIDARG`. I edited my question - added information that I use Outlook 2019, try to delete single email and support only x64. Added also code snippet with `WriteInt32` as you suggested.

Comment: Hard to say what else could be wrong without actually running the code under the debugger. And I'd personally prefer to define the struct in my code rather than rely on writing to memory buffer. Oh, and SBinaryArray is at least 16 bytes under x64 - 4 bytes count, 4 bytes padding, 8 bytes buffer address.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this? Are you trying to avoid having the deleted messages in the Deleted Items folder?

Comment: I edited code snippets. Code snippet no 3 takes into account padding.
Yes, I'm trying to hard delete the message. I'd like to also delete or copy more than one message at once (single message was just starting point). And now I'm just interested why it's not working.

Comment: Added code snippet with structs.

Comment: Hard to say without actually running the code under the debugger, but why not use a wrapper like Redemption (I am its author). It supports deleting (without moving to the Deleted Items folder) multiple messages using RDOFolder.,Items.RemoveMultiple.

Comment: For now I don't want to use 3-rd party. Thanks.